# Not able to apply jQuery code on multiple classes that have the same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I am having some issues with apply jQuery code on multiple classes with the same class name on a page. It looks like the code will only work for one of the class but not for more than one class.

As you can see there are two `TwoColumnUnit` classes on the page but only the first `TwoColumnUnit` is picking up the jQuery code but not picking up the second `TwoColumnUnit` class.

How can I fix the code so that, this code will work on multiple classes with the same class name?

```js
$('.TwoColumnUnit').each(function() {
  var pairs = [document.querySelector('.TwoColumnUnit_Left'), document.querySelector('.TwoColumnUnit_Right')];
  pairs.forEach(function(pair) {
    if (pair) {
      var boxes = pair.getElementsByClassName('col-sm-12 col-md-6');
      var maxHeight = 0;
      Array.from(boxes).forEach(function(box) {
        box.style.height = ''; // Reset
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, box.offsetHeight);
      });
      Array.from(boxes).forEach(function(box) {
        box.style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="TwoColumnUnit">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Left">
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
          <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
          <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Right">
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
          <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
          <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="TwoColumnUnit">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Left">
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
          <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
          <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Right">
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
          <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
          <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelector()` will only select the first occurrence in `.TwoColumnUnit`. You should use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead.

Also, I will suggest you to avoid mixing JS and jQuery.

**Demo:**

```js
$('.TwoColumnUnit').each(function () {
    var pairs = [$(this).find('.TwoColumnUnit_Left'), $(this).find('.TwoColumnUnit_Right')];
    pairs.forEach(function (pair) {
        if (pair.length > 0) {
            var boxes = pair.find('.col-sm-12.col-md-6');
            var maxHeight = 0;
            boxes.each(function () {
                $(this).css('height', ''); // Reset
                maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
            });
            boxes.css('height', maxHeight + 'px');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="TwoColumnUnit">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Left">
        <div class="newsLetterDiv">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="left_Side">
                    <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
                    <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right_Side">
                    <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsLetterDiv">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="left_Side">
                    <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
                    <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right_Side">
                    <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Right">    
        <div class="newsLetterDiv">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="left_Side">
                    <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
                    <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right_Side">
                    <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsLetterDiv">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="left_Side">
                    <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
                    <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right_Side">
                    <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="TwoColumnUnit">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Left">
        <div class="newsLetterDiv">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="left_Side">
                    <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
                    <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right_Side">
                    <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsLetterDiv">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="left_Side">
                    <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
                    <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right_Side">
                    <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Right">    
        <div class="newsLetterDiv">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="left_Side">
                    <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
                    <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right_Side">
                    <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsLetterDiv">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="left_Side">
                    <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
                    <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right_Side">
                    <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your DOM selectors pick up the same two divs

You want to use jQuery as much as possible or none at all

Note I do not need to test the existence of the divs since the script will ignore them if they are not found

```js
$('.TwoColumnUnit').each(function() {
  const $boxes = $(this).find('.newsLetterDiv > div'); // the divs right under newsLetter
  var maxHeights = $boxes
    .map(function() { // jQuery map
      return +this.offsetHeight; // the DOM property
    })
    .get(); // array
  const maxHeight = Math.max(...maxHeights); // find the tallest
  $boxes.each(function() {
    $(this).css({ "height": `${maxHeight}px` });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="TwoColumnUnit">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Left">
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
          <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
          <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Right">
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
          <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
          <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="TwoColumnUnit">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Left">
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
          <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
          <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Right">
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
          <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
          <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No jQuery

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.TwoColumnUnit').forEach(unit => {
  const boxes = unit.querySelectorAll('.newsLetterDiv > div'); // the divs right under newsLetter
  const maxHeights = [...boxes].map(box => +box.offsetHeight);
  const maxHeight = Math.max(...maxHeights); // find the tallest
  boxes.forEach(box => box.style.height = `${maxHeight}px`);
});
```

```html
<div class="TwoColumnUnit">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Left">
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
          <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
          <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Right">
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
          <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
          <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="TwoColumnUnit">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Left">
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
          <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
          <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Right">
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
          <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsLetterDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="left_Side">
          <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
          <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right_Side">
          <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for showing a better approach to this.

Comment: Look again. I made a  plain JS version too